# Entity Framework Core can't translate new columns

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I got a DbContext class:

```
 internal class ServicesContext: DbContext
 {
 internal DbSet<CurrentRunningServiceDbModel> CurrentRunningServices { get; set; }
  ...
 }
```

and the `CurrentRunningServiceDbModel` which represents the CurrentRunningServices table:

```
class CurrentRunningServiceDbModel
{ 
        public string DataCenter { get; set; }
        public string Service { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I could then use the context without any problem. Now I need to add some new columns to the db table so I did it and added 2 more columns. I then simply added 2 more members to `CurrentRunningServiceDbModel` including `public bool IsActive{ get; set; }`. However now that I try running a simple linq query I get an exception:

```
var isRunning = dbContext.CurrentRunningServices.Where(crs => crs.DataCenter == dataCenter && crs.Name == name && crs.IsActive).Count() > 0;
```

The exception says that the clause can't be translated. It happens only for the new columns I added to the db table and for the rest it still works fine.

Do I need to do something special so EF would pick up the changes in my db?

Comment: It depends. If you use EF Core with model first, then you need to create a migration and apply it to the database (instead of manually adding the columns yourself). If you use DB first, then you need to scaffold again.

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu I just added the DbSet to the context class and overridden the OnConfiguring method with options.UseSqlServer(connectionString)

Comment: Search the solution for a folder called `Migrations`. If you have that one, then it's code first, if you don't, it's probably DB first.

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu Don't have that folder. So if it's DB first, what does it mean to scaffold again? Can you give an example?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://entityframeworkcore.com/approach-database-first). You can probably get away with it by altering the code in your `ServicesContext` class, `onModelCreating` method. Add the new properties there and you should be good.

Comment: have your db the columns added? If not you need do migration or other tool that the project use. Then you can use Any() instead of Count() > 0

Answer (score 0):

1- do you have your 'CurrentRunningServiceDbModel' in SQL server or other database software which you are using it?

2- did you use Migration for your new changes?

if you have your database on SQL or other Softwares you need migration to update them. otherwise, you need to add your database first.